# Окончание ресайза окна javascript

Tags: javascript

Если нужно выполнять какой-то код при изменении размера окна браузера, то повесим обработчик события  resize на window:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(e){//код....});
```

Но вот как быть, если не нужно выполнять код в момент ресайза, а необходимо только после его завершения?
Например начинаем изменять размер окна, пока размер изменяется ничего не происходит, а как только ресайз окончен, выполнить код.

Comment: Решение есть тут https://stackoverflow.com/q/5489946/5441700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <script>

    $(window).bind("resize",function(){ //Подключам событие изменение размеров Окна
    window_resize(); //Вызываем функцию Обработки окна
    return false});`

var resizeTimeoutId; //Таймер задержки исполнения

function window_resize() {
     clearTimeout(resizeTimeoutId); //удаляем все предыдущие события "Дребезга `контактов"
     resizeTimeoutId = setTimeout('alert_And_ResizeCode();', 10);
}

function alert_And_ResizeCode(){alert("Есть Cмена размера окна ");/*Тут Обработка события*/
 };

</script>
```

Comment: Ну понятно, спасибо. Я изучил материал по ссылке что дал Visman, походу это единственно оптимальное решение для задачи.... хотя оно мне и не очень нравиться... каждый раз дергать таймеры...